# Is Acetanilide toxic to fish?

Tags: toxicity

I understand that acetanilide can hydrolyze to aniline and assume that will happen if that gets added to an aquarium, thus causing toxicity?

I have a solution that is $3\%$ hydrogen peroxide and $0.25\%$ acetanilide that I'd like to add to my fish and shrim aquarium to kill some algae.

Comment: If there is any miracle mixture of chemicals that would kill algae but not fish, then I'm sure that it is sold in aquarium stores. Rather than experimenting on your fish, I suggest you buy some commercial product if it is available.

Answer (score 1):

When I checked the SDS of acetanilide on Sigma-Aldrich [website](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=US&language=en&productNumber=112933&brand=ALDRICH&PageToGoToURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sigmaaldrich.com%2Fcatalog%2Fproduct%2Faldrich%2F112933%3Flang%3Den), I saw that it is harmful to aquatic life. 
So, there is no exception whether it is an alga or fish to kill. I suggest you not use acetanilide in the aquarium.